# Autoresize textarea for IE 11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, textarea, web-component

Auto resize textarea that resizing to 10 rows then scrollbar works. Its working but with scrollbar blinkig and text jumping. So i need it for angular project which then compiles this code to web component.
here is some code i have:
jsbin.com/qivakevaxa/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Your code works well on Chrome and IE 11 browser on my side.

If you mean you want to use your code in angular application, you could refer to the following code:

Code in about.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  templateUrl: './about.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./about.component.css']
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onchange(event) {
    event.target.style.height = 'auto';
    event.target.style.height = event.target.scrollHeight+'px';
    event.target.scrollTop = event.target.scrollHeight;
    console.log( "Input Event:", event.target.value );
  }
}
```

code in the about.component.html:

```
<textarea id="mytextarea" (input)="onchange($event)" rows='3'>Type here and I’ll resize.</textarea>
```

code in the about.component.css:

```
    textarea {
      display: block;
      /* resize: none; */
      box-sizing:border-box;
      max-height:200px;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it works in angular. But i mean it's scrollbar blinking and text jumping.
I don't know how to fix it

Comment: The result like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtKhn.gif), it seems works well on my side(using IE 11.523.17134.0 version). Try to clear the browser cache and retest it.

Comment: Yes, i did it.
When i press enter quickly, it works bad.